# jQuery validate doesn't work with one page scroll

Tags: jquery, validation, scroll

I am using Pete R's one page scroll(http://www.thepetedesign.com/demos/onepage_scroll_demo.html) and trying to use the jQuery validate-function for validating a form. 
I need to include 
 for the scroll to work but when I include that snippet, the validate-function stops working.

Here's my includes for validate:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.7/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
```

Here's my validation:

```
     $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#mycontactform").validate({
            debug: false,
            rules: {

                email: {
                    required: true,
                    email: true
                }
            },
            messages: {

                email: "*",
            },
            submitHandler: function(form) {
                // do other stuff for a valid form

            } }); });
```

What can I do?

Okey, read jQuery's documentation and solved that problem, but now it won't scroll down:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$.noConflict();
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
        $("#mycontactform").validate({
            debug: false,
            rules: {

                email: {
                    required: true,
                    email: true
                }
            },
            messages: {

                email: "*",
            },
            submitHandler: function(form) {
                // do other stuff for a valid form
            $.post("send.php", $("#mycontactform").serialize(),  function(response) {


});
$(".main").moveDown();
return false;

            } }); });

    </script>
```

The page is just refreshing.

Answer (score 0):

hii this is due to multiple java script framework.

use jquery.noConflict()

like

jq = jquery.noConflict() ;

jq(document){

...
....

your code with jq

}

Comment: Thank you. But I changed my validation to jq = jquery.noConflict() ;
        jq(document).ready(function(){
            jq("#mycontactform").validate({

But still not working

Comment: use firebug tool with firefox and debug your code you will get the error message.

Comment: please visit this link for jquery validation http://www.raymondcamden.com/index.cfm/2009/2/10/An-Introduction-to-jQuery-and-Form-Validation-2

Comment: Thanks! But I've got a new problem. Check the first post.

Answer (score 0):

In these cases, it would be to develop your own validator.

1 .- Adding rqs classe you require your order is validated.

```
<input type="text" id="txtOrigen" class="rqs" style="border-color: red;">
```

2 .- Add the script before sending the form

```
$("#mycontactform").find(".rqs").each(function (r, n) {
       this.style.borderColor = ""
       if (this.id !== "" && this.value === "") {
              rqs = r
              this.style.borderColor = "red"
       }
})

if (rqs > 0) {
     $('#lblMessege').text("Campos requeridos, favor de verificar...").fadeIn(150).delay(4000).fadeOut("slow")
     return false
}

$.post("send.php", $("#mycontactform").serialize(),  function(response) {

});
```

imagen (https://i.stack.imgur.com/a5F9r.png)